# In tmux session, cannot connect to X server after ssh'ing

Tags: ssh, x11, tmux

At work, I have a desktop with a monitor and a few running tmux sessions. At home, I frequently ssh into that desktop and enter my running tmux sessions. When I ssh from home, I do *not* want to use X11, so I do not use the `-X` flag. When I go back to work (after ssh'ing from home) and use those tmux sessions on desktop, I can no longer do anything that would spawn a GUI. I can't open files in evince. When I try use matplotlib, I get a `: cannot connect to X server` message.

After ssh'ing and opening an existing tmux session from home, how do I later reattach the ability to open up GUI stuff on the desktop?

The ssh'ing from home seems to make the tmux session forget that it can spawn GUI stuff.

EDIT:

Comment: Bit confused. Are you using the `-X` flag now or not? You can only do X11 stuff through SSH if that's set.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I never use the -X flag, anywhere. I do not intend on doing X11 stuff through SSH. I only intend on using X11 on my desktop, where the tmux session actually lives. I'll update the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I need to do is set the DISPLAY environment variable to :0.0. I think the issue was that I am using the fish shell, and I need to use the -x flag to set when doing this:

```
set -x DISPLAY :0.0
```

Comment: Note that the correct value for `DISPLAY` might be different from `:0.0`. A quick way to find out is to create a new tmux window and `echo $DISPLAY` there.

Comment: Just extending the comment from @j08lue; in my case `echo $DISPLAY` returned `localhost:10.0` and running `set DISPLAY localhost:0.0` did the trick.

Comment: Does anyone know a `bash` equivalent, or a cross-shell version? `set -x` just increases verbosity for me in `bash`. @IsaacS, did you have to `set DISPLAY localhost:10.0` instead or did `localhost:0.0` work for you?

Comment: On bash, you should be able to use `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.

Comment: I don't like this solution, since I have to do it for every new window for the rest of the session (which lasts weeks for me). And it happens even when I'm back on my main X11 system creating new windows.
How can we get tmux to stop unsetting `$DISPLAY`?

Comment: Where exactly is this meant to be set?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. I normally use `tmux` as part of a multi-monitor X11 desktop environment, and sometimes ssh in from a chromebook, which doesn't support X11 or set `$DISPLAY`.  The answer by @chrisdembia works, but requires changing `DISPLAY` in each new window for the rest of the tmux session, which is a pain.

A permanent solution is to remove `DISPLAY` from the tmux `update-environment` variable in the tmux settings.  You can see your current value with this command:

```
tmux show-options -g update-environment
```

To remove it, I added this line to my `~/.tmux.conf` file, including everything but `DISPLAY`:

```
set-option -g update-environment "SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
```

This is further explained at [Reset the shell DISPLAY variable in a tmux session over ssh](https://goosebearingbashshell.github.io/2017/12/07/reset-display-variable-in-tmux.html), which explains why `DISPLAY` is there by default, for a different common use case.

Answer (score 0):

tmux fight with matplotlib:

```
export MPLBACKEND='Agg'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. To make the answer useful to a wider range of audiences, would you mind editing your post to explain _why_ this will serve to solve the OPs problem (possibly with links to external sources as reference)?

Comment: @AdminBee i have tested this configuration on my tmux, my answer doesn't cover all of this kind of problems. it solved my problem.